# Regex remove all occurrences of multiple characters in a string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL I want to replace all characters `(;<>)` occurrences in a string.

My query:

```
update table_name set text = regexp_replace(text, '/[(;<>)]+/g', '');
```

I think my regexp is wrong. Can anyone help me out with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the much faster [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for this simple case:

```
UPDATE tbl SET text = translate(text, '(;<>)', '');
```

Every character in the second parameter that has no counterpart in the third parameter is replaced with nothing.

The regular expression solution could look like this:

```
regexp_replace(text, '[(;<>)]', '', 'g');
```

Essential element is the 4th parameter `'g'` to replace "globally" instead of just the first match. The second parameter is a character class.
You were on the right track, just a matter of syntax for [`regexp_replace()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER).

#### Hint on `UPDATE`

If you don't expect *all* rows to be changed, I would strongly advise to adapt your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    text =  translate(text, '(;<>)', '')
WHERE  text <> translate(text, '(;<>)', '');
```

This way you avoid (expensive) empty updates. (`NULL` is covered automatically in this particular case.)

Comment: Awesome. Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the OP's regex pattern is correct (it does have /g flag), it should just have been written a bit different in Postgres. Anyway, very good point regarding `translate`.

Comment: @raina77ow: Yes, just a matter of syntax for the regular expression. I added the parenthesis to my example, seems the OP wants to replace those, too.