# How to remove substrings that follow a pattern

Tags: postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

I have a query that returns a column with a string I need to clean up.  I would like to remove the portion of this string that starts with ",id:" and ends right before ")".  The string could have many occurrences of the substring to be removed. The alphanumeric substring that follows "id:" is always the same length.

This is a sample string:

```
(label:Boston,include:true,id:9fc53def-0b9d-45cb-8f12-d42c3ca70ab2),
(label:Cambridge,include:true,id:dda3d6d7-f9d1-45ac-ac6e-5866b356966e)
```

This is the string I would like to see at the end:

```
(label:Boston,include:true),
(label:Cambridge,include:true)
```

Comment: Is the string to remove always a UUID in standard Postgres output format? Lower case hex with 4 dashes.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
          '(label:Cambridge,include:true,id:dda3d6d7-f9d1-45ac-ac6e-5866b356966e)',
          ',?\mid:.{36}',  -- pattern
          '',            -- replacement
          'g'            -- flag: replace multiple occurrences
       );
         regexp_replace         
════════════════════════════════
 (label:Cambridge,include:true)
(1 row)
```

Explaining the pattern:

- `,?` matches a comma, if there is one
- `\m` matches the beginning of a word
- `.{36}` matches 36 arbitrary characters

Comment: Thanks @laurenz, worked like a charm.  Could you help me understand the use of "?", "." and "{}" in the pattern?

Comment: I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will hepls you......

```
select SUBSTRING('label:Boston,include:true,id:9fc53def-0b9d-45cb-8f12-d42c3ca70ab2',1,LEN('label:Boston,include:true,id:9fc53def-0b9d-45cb-8f12-d42c3ca70ab2')-40) as stringaa;
```

Comment: The example string is one value, not two.  The pattern can repeat multiple times within a single value.

Answer (score 0):

> starts with ",id:" and ends right before ")"

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(string, ',id:[0-9a-f-]{36}\)', ')', 'g');
```

Neither comma nor closing parenthesis are optional in your description.

Or with an even more rigid pattern to match standard Postgres UUID format as [described in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html):

```sql
SELECT regexp_replace(string
                    , ',id:[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}\)'
                    , ')', 'g');
```

Related:

- [Avoid PG::InvalidTextRepresentation error when using Postgres UUID in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338873/avoid-pginvalidtextrepresentation-error-when-using-postgres-uuid-in-rails)
- [Regex remove all occurrences of multiple characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953099/regex-remove-all-occurrences-of-multiple-characters-in-a-string/14953266#14953266)